# Probability : A bag contains 12 pair socks . Four socks are picked up at random. Find the probability that there is at least one pair.

Tags: probability

Probability : A bag contains 12 pair socks . Four socks are picked up at random. Find the probability that there is at least one pair.

My approach :

Number of ways of selecting 4 socks from 24 socks is n(s) = $^{24}C_4$

The number of ways of selecting 4 socks from different pairs is n(E) = $^{12}C_4$

$$\Rightarrow P(E) = \frac{^{12}C_4 }{^{24}C_4}$$

Therefore, the probability of getting at least one pair is

$$1- \frac{^{12}C_4 }{^{24}C_4}$$

But the answer is $$1- \frac{^{12}C_4 \times 2^4}{^{24}C_4}$$... Please guide the error .. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the 12 pairs are different.

The number of ways of selecting 4 socks is $24*23*22*21$.

The number of ways of selecting 4 socks of no pair is $24*22*20*18$.

The chances of not getting a pair, then is $18*20 / 23*21$, or $120/161$. (by removing the common factors $22*24$.

The chances of getting at least one pair is then $41/161$

The error in your calculation, is that you are only counting one sock in each pair, similar to the second line of mine being $12*11*10*9$.  There are two socks in each pair, so you need to realise that either of the two can be fetched when a pair is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Let the Event Probability of Selecting 4 Socks such that there is at least one Pair is $A$

Let the Event Probability of selecting 4 Socks such that there is exactly one pair is $B$

Let the  Event Probability of selecting 4 Socks such that there is exactly Two pairs is $C$.

Then

$$P(A)=P(B)+P(C)$$

$$P(B)= \frac{\binom{12}{1}\binom{11}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{10}{1}}{\binom{24}{4}}=\frac{40}{161}$$

$$P(C)=\frac{\binom{12}{2}}{\binom{24}{4}}=\frac{1}{161}$$

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the second line.  The number of ways to select four different pairs *must be multiplied by* the number of ways to select *just one* sock from each of those four selected pairs.

This is:  (<sup>12</sup>C<sub>4</sub> × 2<sup>4</sup>)